# When using Parse on Buddy, where can I find Client Key?

Tags: parse-platform, key, client, buddy.com

I am new to Parse on Buddy. On my client iOS app, it requests a client key in my `appDelegate` under `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
Parse.setApplicationId("7a8sd9f078a9s07f0a8", clientKey: "your_client_key")
```

However, there is no such key that I can find. Under App Settings, Security and Keys, it offers the following:

- Application ID
- Master Key
- Mongo DB URL
- File Key
- Webhook Key

However, none of these match.

Code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

     Parse.setApplicationId("d602af8b-bba8-4f52-9c10-c367bcff49", clientKey: "https://parse.buddy.com/parse")        
    PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
    let defaultACL = PFACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    //defaultACL.getPublicReadAccess = true

    PFACL.setDefault(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser: true)

    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.background {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.responds(to: #selector(getter: UIApplication.backgroundRefreshStatus))
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.responds(to: #selector(UIApplicationDelegate.application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)))
        var noPushPayload = false;
        if let options = launchOptions {
            noPushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] != nil;
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpened(launchOptions: launchOptions)
        }
    }


    return true
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code snippet? stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And make the effort to complete the 2-minute site tour as well.

Answer (score 1):

I updated our [FAQ](https://buddy.com/parse/frequently-asked-questions):

The open-source Parse Server (upon which Parse on Buddy is built) does not require the use of client-side keys. This includes the client key, JavaScript key, .NET key, and REST API key. The Application ID is sufficient to secure your app. Parse Server's [wiki](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-Server-Guide#using-parse-sdks-with-parse-server) shows initialization of the Parse SDKs by passing an empty string for the client key.

That said, adding the ability to specify any of these four keys in the dashboard, and enforce that any clients passing a key matches, is upcoming. (reference: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Parse-Server-Guide#keys)